# How to get the count and name of each element?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the total count from the output of this query:

```
SELECT category as every, COUNT(*)
FROM categorydata
GROUP BY category
```

The output looks like this:

```
    every
--------------------------------------  
    TRAI-VPURA  68
    SCHO-VPURA  44
    TECH-BLORE  122
    REAL-VPURA  193
    BIZS-BLORE  2816
    HOSP-VPURA  30
    VIDYARANYAPURA  182
    PLAC-BLORE  461
    business    471
    COLL-VPURA  10
    SOFT-BLORE  362
    TIE-BLORE   95
```

I want to get the total count, which is: `3538 (as total)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `with rollup` like

```
SELECT category as every, COUNT(*)
FROM categorydata
GROUP BY category
WITH ROLLUP
```

This will add an extra record with the total sum.

**Edit**:
Or, if you *just* want the total sum (without the group results) you could of course simply do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categorydata
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT sum(tmpTable.every) as every from 
         (SELECT count(*) as every 
                 from categorydata 
           GROUP BY category) as tmpTable;
```

you don't need to have **GROUP BY** clause. It will generate the same result.
**Explanation:** The code in parens is just creating a temporary table with only on field named **every** the temporary table needs to be named as "tmpTable" in my case. Now our query becomes **select sum(every) as every from tmpTable**. The **tmpTable** is a dynamically created temporary table which is having single field name **every** which is actually the count of the rows present under **category** of your table **categorydata**.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT sum(cnt)
FROM
  (SELECT category AS EVERY,
          COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM categorydata
   GROUP BY category) AS tmp;
```