# Sum column values in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to sum the values of the "Total Work Assigned" and "Not Called" columns.

Here is my `table` HTML

```
<table border=1 id="category">
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User Belongs</th>
        <th>Total Work Assigned</th>
        <th>Not Called</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>vidyaranyapura</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>172</td>
        <td>156</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sahasra</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>global</td>
        <td>Not Assigned</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is snippet

```js
$('#category tr td').text(function(i,el){
   console.log(parseInt(el,10));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1 id="category">
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User Belongs</th>
        <th>Total Work Assigned</th>
        <th>Not Called</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>vidyaranyapura</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>172</td>
        <td>156</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sahasra</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>global</td>
        <td>Not Assigned</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h3>MY EXPECTED OUTPUT</h3>
<table border=1 id="same_id_wont_work_changed_for_demo_only">
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User Belongs</th>
        <th>Total Work Assigned</th>
        <th>Not Called</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>vidyaranyapura</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>172</td>
        <td>156</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sahasra</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>global</td>
        <td>Not Assigned</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>672</td>
        <td>506</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle for my expected output:  https://jsfiddle.net/2g29c8uv/16/

Comment: You mean to say don't want tp first two recordes, Right?

Comment: If you're trying to total the 3rd and 4th columns, why are you doing it after the template has rendered? why not total them as its being generated? what templating library are you using, and how are you outputting your table?

Comment: yes it is --- i don't want first 2 records

Comment: @haxxxton, i'm using `php` and `data is obtained` from `mysql database`

Comment: can you post your `php` code you're using to output the table please

Comment: @haxxxton, by the way i'm using this query which is posted by me only  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712550/how-to-get-the-count-and-name-of-each-element/41712614#41712614

Comment: @user5405873, i dont need the `mysql`, im asking for the code you're using to output the `table`. It probably involves a number of `<?php echo '<tr>'; ?>` looking lines.

Comment: as @haxxxton said. Doing it in the templating phase would be easier and faster.

Comment: I have modified your JSfiddle code now it's working :[jsfiddle.net/2g29c8uv/19/](https://jsfiddle.net/2g29c8uv/19/)

Comment: @ZeeshanMahboob, hit that _tidy_ button and alert the correct variable for `total work assigned` : https://jsfiddle.net/2g29c8uv/22/

Comment: @ZeeshanMahboob, post your Answer so that i can respect your answer

Comment: @user5405873, happy to post a `PHP` solution so that you have the correct rendered output if you can post your code

Comment: @haxxxton, ok i'm posting my `php code` i'm using custom `ms sql to mysql query` here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/c86jLfa9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/zxooa1j4/1/

```
var sum1 = 0;
var sum2 = 0;
$("#category tr").not(':first').not(':last').each(function() {
  sum1 +=  getnum($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text());
  sum2 +=  getnum($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text());
  function getnum(t){
    if(isNumeric(t)){
        return parseInt(t,10);
    }
    return 0;
    function isNumeric(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
  }
});
$("#sum1").text(sum1);
$("#sum2").text(sum2);
```

isNumeric() function is quoted from this answer:

[Is there any function like IsNumeric in javascript to validate numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers)

HTML:

```
<table border=1 id="category">
  <tr>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>User Belongs</th>
    <th>Total Work Assigned</th>
    <th>Not Called</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>vidyaranyapura</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>172</td>
    <td>156</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sahasra</td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>350</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>global</td>
    <td>Not Assigned</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="sum1"></td>
    <td id="sum2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this isnt Golf, but could this be more efficient by doing the `parseInt(t,10)` and THEN checking if `!isNaN && isFinite` before returning either it or `0`. (Saves parsing to float and then re-parsing to int)?

Comment: Thanks. You are right haxxxton. This function is just cheking if the value is Numeric or not. I wrote the example in that way just to make it clear.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716468/is-there-any-function-like-isnumeric-in-javascript-to-validate-numbers

Comment: What i mean is, this data is coming directly from values that were stored in an SQL database, so they have already had a level of validation performed upon them, so perhaps anything outside of a `parseInt` is unnecessary code overhead? (more of a question/comment than a critique :) )

Comment: Yeah, this function will be an overhead if all the values are guaranteed to be Numerical. But some people may think it's worth implementing just in case when the PHP code doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `PHP` that you provided in your fiddle. You can actually total the values while you're looping through them for output to the display.

Simply replace this `foreach` section

```
$table2 = '<table  id="all_category_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"><tr><th>User Name</th><th>User Belongs to</th><th>Total Work Assigned</th><th>Not Called</th><th>Follow Up</th><th>Intrested</th><th>Not Intrested</th></tr>';

foreach($totalresult as $totalresults) {
    $table2 .= "<tr><td>".$totalresults['username'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['userbelongs'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['totalvalue'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['Notcalled'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['followUp'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['intrested'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['notIntrested'].
    "</td></tr>";
}

$table2. = '</table>';

echo $table2;
```

with the following that includes the addition and output

```
$table2 = '<table  id="all_category_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"><tr><th>User Name</th><th>User Belongs to</th><th>Total Work Assigned</th><th>Not Called</th><th>Follow Up</th><th>Intrested</th><th>Not Intrested</th></tr>';
$totalValue = 0;
$notCalledValue = 0;
foreach($totalresult as $totalresults) {
    // addition of totalValue
    $totalValue = $totalValue + $totalresults['totalvalue'];
    // addition of notCalledValue
    $notCalledValue = $notCalledValue + $totalresults['Notcalled'];

    $table2 .= "<tr><td>".$totalresults['username'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['userbelongs'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['totalvalue'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['Notcalled'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['followUp'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['intrested'].
    "</td><td>".$totalresults['notIntrested'].
    "</td></tr>";
}
// output of totalValue and notCalledValue
$table2 .= "<tr><td>".
    "</td><td>".
    "</td><td>".$totalValue.
    "</td><td>".$notCalledValue.
    "</td><td>".
    "</td><td>".
    "</td><td>".
    "</td></tr>";

$table2. = '</table>';
echo $table2;
```

**NOTE**: this assumes that the `$totalresults['totalvalue']` and `$totalresults['Notcalled']` keys in your data are numbers.