# Attempting to sum html tables results in numbers being concatenated like strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

While trying to get the sum total of the values of an html table column, my variable is returning concatenated strings: instead of `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`, I am seeing `1 + 2 + 3 = 123`.

The "votes" column values are incremented by an ajax call when the users click on the colors, which is correct.  But I also hope to see the sum of all values when "total" is clicked.

### Jquery:

```
$('#total').on('click', function() {
  var sumofval = 0;
  $(".val").each(function () {
    sumofval = sumofval + ($(this).html());
    $('#totalr').html(sumofval);
    console.log(sumofval);
  });
});
```

### The HTML Color-Votes Table:

```
<table id="tcol" style="width:60%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td id="red"><a href="#">Red</a></td>
        <td id="redr" class="val"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="orange"><a href="#">Orange</a></td>
        <td id="oranger" class="val"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="yellow"><a href="#">Yellow</a></td>
        <td id="yellowr" class="val"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="green"><a href="#">Green</a></td>
        <td id="greenr" class="val"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></td>
        <td id="bluer" class="val"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="indigo"><a href="#">Indigo</a></td>
        <td id="indigor" class="val"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="total"><a href="#">TOTAL</a></td>
        <td id="totalr"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You add strings to eachother. Use parseInt to cast a string to an integer. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum column values in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756911/sum-column-values-in-table)

Comment: Wimanicesir, I already tried, but I get "NaN"

Comment: you get `NaN` because you not have any value there currently.. its just empty field. add a values and it will not be `NaN`

Comment: YosefTukachinsky, the values are added when I click on each color via Ajax, it's just that the values are not displayed immediately after the page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert it to number. (You can do it by adding `+` at the start, or using `parseInt` function)
2. `sumofval = sumofval +..` can be replaced with `sumofval+=..`
3. do `$('#totalr').html(sumofval);` at each step in the loop is redandent. better do it once at the end

```js
$('#total').on('click', function() {
var sumofval = 0;
$(".val").each(function () {
    sumofval += +$(this).html() || 0;
});
$('#totalr').html(sumofval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tcol" style="width:60%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Votes</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td id="red"><a href="#">Red</a></td>
<td id="redr" class="val"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="orange"><a href="#">Orange</a></td>
<td id="oranger" class="val">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="yellow"><a href="#">Yellow</a></td>
<td id="yellowr" class="val">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="green"><a href="#">Green</a></td>
<td id="greenr" class="val">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></td>
<td id="bluer" class="val">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="indigo"><a href="#">Indigo</a></td>
<td id="indigor" class="val">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="total"><a href="#">TOTAL</a></td>
<td id="totalr"></td>
</tr>
```

Also you can do:

```
$('#totalr').html(Array.from($(".val")).reduce(function(a,b){return (+$(b).html() ||0)+a}, 0));
```

Comment: Yosef Tukachinsky, is not working, I still get the values one after other or NaN displayed. Remember the that values are not displayed immediately in the table, they are displayed when I click in each color respectively.

Comment: good to know.. I updated the snipped. just cast `NaN` to `0`. take a look now

Comment: Excellent, Yosef, thank you so much. Can you also explain me a little bit how this works? I mean, how "|| 0" changed the output?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to parse strings and convert them to integers. Then you can add them to the `sumofval` correctly.

```js
$('#total').on('click', function() {
  var sumofval = 0;
  $(".val").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() !== '') {
      sumofval = sumofval + parseInt(($(this).text()));
      $('#totalr').text(sumofval);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tcol" style="width:60%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td id="red"><a href="#">Red</a></td>
    <td id="redr" class="val">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="orange"><a href="#">Orange</a></td>
    <td id="oranger" class="val"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="yellow"><a href="#">Yellow</a></td>
    <td id="yellowr" class="val">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="green"><a href="#">Green</a></td>
    <td id="greenr" class="val">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a></td>
    <td id="bluer" class="val">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="indigo"><a href="#">Indigo</a></td>
    <td id="indigor" class="val">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="total"><a href="#">TOTAL</a></td>
    <td id="totalr"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, consider using [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the value of the element instead of [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the only thing that changed was NaN to be displayed in the <td> id="totalr" cell. I guess it was because if the .text() function, but still don't get the total sum of the values.

Comment: @JoeSmith use a conditional to check if the cell element is empty. See updated example above.

Comment: Thank you so much, Juan. Just one more question, why is it necessary the conditional in this function?

Comment: Because if the cell happens to be empty, you don't want to add a blank line to `sumofval`. A conditional prevents this by checking if the cell is empty to begin with.

Comment: Ok, will the blank line (empty cell) prevent the next statement to execute (do the sum of the values are present in the table)?

Comment: No, it will continue to iterate over the remaining cell elements (if any).

Answer (score 0):

If one term isn't a number, JavaScript will treat everything as string and concatenate the values instead.   So you need to make sure the value's you're adding up are all number types:

```
$('#total').on('click', function() {

    var sumofval = 0;
    $(".val").each(function () {
        sumofval = sumofval + getInt($(this).html());
        $('#totalr').html(sumofval);  //this line should be moved outside .each loop
        console.log(sumofval);
    )};

});

function getInt(t){
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(t)) && isFinite(t)){
        return parseInt(t,10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `getInt` can be changed to simple `(+num || 0)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked too. Can you explain it a little bit too?

Comment: `+num` convert it to number. in the case it cannot be converted (like empty string) it will give `NaN`, which is falsy value. using `||` you give alternative value, if the first is falsy. in the abode case, its 0

Comment: Yosef, ok, but what is the utility of the value 0 in this case? I mean if I am getting NaN, why should I use this?